# Published VS Code Extension working differently

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, publish

I've published a VS Code Extension that I've developed by following the steps outlined in the following website: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/publishing-extension

While testing the extension to make sure it functions like its supposed to, I saw that a few features I included aren't visible or accessible - and yes, these features were visible and accessible when I was testing the extension in the development environment.

I've tried uninstalling the extension from VS Code and publishing it again while generating a .vsix file again, but nothing has been working. How do I fix this?

Comment: compare the code of development and the code in the vsix file (zip file) downloaded from the marketplace and the code in the users extensions folder after installation

Comment: I compared the code, and its exactly the same. The code in the VSIX file should provide the same functionality as the code of development.

Comment: if the code in the `dev` folder and the `user/extensions` folder are the same you have a big problem

Comment: I compared the code in "extension-name".vsix file and the "extension-name"/"src" folder?

Comment: none of these is used by VSC, look in the extensions folder where VSC installs the extensions

Comment: add different `console.log` statements to the `activate` functions you find to see which folder is used by VSC.

Comment: You can also create a vsix file and install that, without having to publish it. This should help you to debug your problem.

Comment: The code in .vscode/extensions/"extension-name"/out/"a file".js is the same as the code in the out/"a file".js folder in VSC @rioV8

Comment: I created a vsix file and inspected it without installing it, and there didn't seem to be a problem with the code in that file.

Comment: Update I've fixed it, just had to just the version before publishing again...

Comment: How do you suppose VSC would know from querying the Marketplace that there is an update of the extension

Comment: I had unpublished and removed the extension from the marketplace, so I thought that when I publish the extension again, it would not query an old version as (I assumed) it doesn't have access to it.